# How to prove that in intuitionistic logic the contrapositive law is disallowed?

Tags: logic

here are my efforts:

I need to show that $(P \supset Q) \equiv (\neg Q \supset \neg P)$

for this I need to construct a kripke model. I construct the following model:

$K = ({0,1}, \leq , \models)$

then I define the followings for $A$ and $B$

$0 \nvDash A$ $1 \vDash A$

$ 1 \nvDash B$ $0 \vDash B $

then I say that

$ 1 \nvDash (\neg B \to \neg A) \to A\to B$

Can somebody say what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: Well, you can’t just say things, you have to show them. Also in the convention I’m used to, the greatest world is classical (so that would have to be true in $1$). If you gave some indication why you think this is the case, it would be easy to see if you’re using a different convention or just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

You are violating the rules of [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) : if $B$ is true in "world" $0$ [in symbols : $w_0 \Vdash B$], it cannot be false in $1$, i.e. we cannot have $w_1 \nVdash B$.

We need a three-nodes model with $w_0Rw_1$ and $w_0Rw_2$.

In no node we must have both $A$ and $B$ true, in order to have : $w_0 \nVdash (A \to B)$.