# How to prove that $(P \supset Q) \equiv (\neg Q \supset \neg P)$is disallowed in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic

I have tried defining the following kripke model:

$K = ({0,1}, \leq , \models)$

then I define the followings for $A$ and $B$

$0 \nvDash A$ $1 \vDash A$

$ 1 \nvDash B$ $0 \vDash B $

then I say that

$ 1 \nvDash (\neg B \to \neg A) \to A\to B$

Can somebody say how to do it correctly?

Comment: I see you haven’t followed my advice. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001601/how-to-prove-that-in-intuitionistic-logic-the-contrapositive-law-is-disallowed

Comment: There is a counter model with two nodes, but it’s very hard to tell if you have found it.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen could you please be more specific?